# What is the integration of integral of $\cot(\log(\sin(x))$ ??

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

what is the integration of integral 
$$\int\cot(\log(\sin(x))\, dx$$

I have tried:

Let $\log(\sin(x))=z$ or $\dfrac{1}{\sin(x)}\cos(x)\cdot dx=dz$ , that means $\cot(x)\cdot dx=dz$ $\Longrightarrow$ integration of $dz$ is $z$ then $c=\dfrac{\log(\sin(x))^2}{2}c$ is it true?

Comment: Do you know http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative ?

Comment: i will check it

Comment: No that's wrong. This function [cannot be expressed in terms of standard functions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+Cot%5BLog%5BSin%5Bx%5D%5D%5D).

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\text{Let } u &= \ln(\sin(x))\\
\mathrm du &= \cot(x)\ \mathrm dx\\
\\
\int \cot(x)\ln(\sin(x)) \mathrm dx&= \int u\ \mathrm du\\
&= u^2/2 + C\\
&= \left[\ln(\sin(x))\right]^2/2 + C \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure should be wrong!

You will have $\int\cot z\tan x~dz$ and you still have to change $x$ in terms of $z$ !

Let $u=\sin x$ ,

Then $x=\sin^{-1}u$

$dx=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du$

$\therefore\int\cot\log\sin x~dx=\int\dfrac{\cot\log u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du$

Let $v=\log u$ ,

Then $u=e^v$

$du=e^v~dv$

$\therefore\int\dfrac{\cot\log u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du=\int\dfrac{e^v\cot v}{\sqrt{1-e^{2v}}}dv$

But still highly have no hope to find the nice series form expression......